# Convert SQL to Power BI

Tags: sql, powerbi

I'm very new to Power BI, therefore please be indulgent with me :D

Actually, I have 2 tables called Report and Mails. In the Report table I have a column Racine and in the Mails table I have a column called Body that might contain Racine.

I would like to convert this sql to Power BI

```
select Report.Racine, Mails.Body 
from Report, Mails
where Mails.Body LIKE '%' + Report.UserId + '%';
```

Example:

Table Report

```
Racine
1234
5678
9012
0987
```

Table Mails

```
Body
'abc 1234 AZER'
'PO5678 tgcv'
'YF1234GHQ'
```

The result should be

```
Racine             Body
1234               'abc 1234 AZER'
1234               'YF1234GHQ'
5678               'PO5678 tgcv'
9012               *null*
0987               *null*
```

Is it possible?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a situation where these tables come from different datasource, you can calculate a new table via DAX (Data -> New Table):

```
VAR __tmp1 =
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
            Report[Racine],
            Mails[Body],
            "condition",
                CONTAINSSTRING (
                    SELECTEDVALUE ( Mails[Body] ),
                    SELECTEDVALUE ( Report[Racine] )
                )
        ),
        [condition]
    )
VAR __tmp2 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            Report,
            NOT ( Report[Racine] IN ( CALCULATETABLE ( Report, __tmp1 ) ) )
        ),
        "Body", BLANK (),
        "condition", FALSE
    )
RETURN
    UNION ( __tmp1, __tmp2 )
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, it works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

1. You can import your exact query as per the image below.

   [image]
2. You import both source tables in PowerBI. You will need to write a query in PowerQuery (M) in PowerBI to extract the numeric Racine from the body. You can then merge the data in another M Query or join in your model. If using the latter you will need to "show items with no data" on the visuals so that blanks/nulls appear.

[image]

You can find and example of the M code you need to write [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/PowerQuery-Extract-Numbers-from-A-string-eg-ABCD1234/td-p/198666). Pasted below for convenience.

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "Custom", each Text.Combine(List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(Text.ToList([Name]),each if Value.Is(Value.FromText(_), type number) then _ else null))))
```

Comment: Hello, thx for the 2 answers. But the 2 tables are from excel, can not use the GetData from SqlServer and I do not know M code. The answer from msta42a using DAX is working as I expect. Cheers.